# Firefox Fixed Header acting like absolute

Tags: jquery, css

I have a fixed positioned header and when a user scrolls down the container div, the header's height changes by adding the 'header-fixed' class. It works on Chrome and Explorer 11, but in Firefox 42 doesn't. It acts like an absolute div. The weird thing is when I uncheck the "poosition:fixed" in the 'Developer Tools panel (=inspect element)' and check it again, it works...

here is my site -> http://cookandgrill.gr/preview.php

```
 .header {
    height: 20%;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 15px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #000;
}

.header, .header-fixed {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 499
}
.header-fixed {
    height: 10%;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 15px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #000;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add to the header's parent element:

```
position: static;
```

So in your code it should be added to "container" and look like below (style.css, line 80):

```
.container {
    height: 100%;
    position: static;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

I edited it in "style editor" in dev tools and this solution fixes that bug without changing other elements' behavior. Works also fine in chrome.

Comment: No, unfortunately it didn't work. Also tried add static position in <body> but nothing...

Comment: It's hard to do more from browser's dev tools. Could you share and put here link to zip archive with your website (or only front-end) code?

Comment: I uploaded a copy from where you can test it.
Host: 193.92.107.53
User: cookandgrill
Pass: Crli91?6 
Port: (blank)
Preview: http://cookandgrill.gr.193-92-107-53.linuxzone29.grserver.gr/preview.php

Comment: OK I made simple change in main.js - timeOut function to add class "header-fixed". It is only workaround, not properly fixed bug. To make it better you should fix all html markup errors - check your website here: https://validator.w3.org/ because problem may be somewhere in these errors.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I found the solution: I had to put my header div element outside of the container div.

http://cookandgrill.gr/preview.php

Now seems ok.

Thanks again...